# multiple relationship between 2 table, how to design classes model that mapping with database by hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have 2 tables project and employee have multiple relationship. Project has many employees, employee can join many projects( many to many). project have one employee whose is team leader, an employee can manager many projects(many to one). So how do I design database, and classes model mapping with database. Some one help me
This is my code

class user

```
@Entity(name = "USERS")
public class Users {
@Id
@Column(name = "USER_ID", length = 6)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer userId;
@Column(name = "USER_NAME", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String userName;
@Column(name = "PASS_WORD", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String passWord;
@Column(name = "FULL_NAME", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String fullName;
@Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 50, nullable = false)
private String email;
@Column(name = "PHONE", length = 11, nullable = true)
private String phone;
@Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = true)
private Boolean status;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonIgnore
@JoinTable(name = "USERPROJECT", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = 
 "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID") })
private List<Project> projects;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teamlead")
private List<Project> projectOfTeamLead;
//get set.....
}
```

class project

```
    @Entity(name = "PROJECTS")
    public class Project {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_ID", length = 6)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer projectId;
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_NAME", length = 50, nullable=false)
    private String projectName;
    @Column(name = "USER_CREATE_ID", length = 6, nullable=false)
    private Integer userCreateId;
    //  @Column(name = "TEAM_LEAD_ID", length = 6, nullable=false)
    //  private Integer teamLeadId;
    @Column(name = "TIME_START", nullable=true)
    private Date timeStart;
    @Column(name = "TIME_END", nullable=true)
    private Date timeEnd;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "projects")
    private List<Users> users;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "TEAM_LEAD_ID")
    private Users teamlead;
    //get set...
    }
```

Comment: Sorry joakim, but you should know that I tried design it, but the result is not good, If you dont want to help, you can skip it and dont talk any more. 
I really find it annoying to read your comment. Maybe you have more experience than me, but don't be so arrogant

Comment: I am not arrogant but we have rules here at stackoverflow, on how to ask question and what one can ask about, and those rules applies to everyone. Read the help section and you will understand what I mean.

Comment: Yes,But  I think I don't violate the rules of stackoverflow.  I just want to understand how to do it. I apologize if my question is a bit confusing or impolite ... because my English is a bit bad

Comment: Your question is _to broad_ since you basically ask for a database design from scratch plus that you want help with hibernate mapping and java programming. To make this an appropriate question you need to restrict it to only one area like database design and you need to show some basic effort yourself by including what you have designed so far and telling us what your issue is with this design. Until you have done so your question comes through more as a request than an actual question so I stand by my initial comment, that was deleted, that this is not a free code writing service.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to make your database fit into 3nf (third normal form). You are describing a database that uses two tables, but I think you need three at least, that way you can describe what employees are on what project. A "team" table that uses the PK's from the other two tables should be used. Conventionally, you would name it something like "ProjectEmployees" as it is comprised of the PK's from the "Projects" table and the "Employees" table respectively. I hope that answers your question. If you don't understand what I'm talking about, I highly recommend you watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UrYLYV7WSHM).

Comment: I understand about manytomany, but besides, they have onetomany relationship, and I am so confuse about this relationship

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking me due to the language barrier. The way that you declare a quantitative relationship, like one-to-many, depends on the  DBMS that you are using, like SSMS or MySQL Workbench, or even transact.. You have given little information as to what you want to accomplish specifically. Show your current attempt and an example of what you want to do in your question so that I can better help you. If you are having trouble understanding something, describe exactly where your understanding falls apart. I'm happy to help you, I just need a little more information.

Comment: I edited my question. I config hibernate auto create database

Comment: I think table user_project should have column role, but hibernate cannot mapping with database